# How to resolve “Illegal cyclic inheritance involving trait Iterable” compilation error when using in Scala 2.12.10 and Java 1.8 IDEA?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

It looks like that there is a conflic in Scala compiler. The error occurs in `val list1 = sc.makeRDD(List(1,2,3,4))` in Scala 2.12.10, Spark 2.4.4, and Java 1.8 IDEA.

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
object WordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val config = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("WordCount")
    val sc =new SparkContext(config)
    val list1 = sc.makeRDD(List(1,2,3,4))
  }
}
```

Comment: In your case you seem to be using the right versions of everything, but I just got this same error when trying to use an incorrect version of Scala which was not matching the Scala version in the `pom.xml`.
In my case that meant I had to run with a Scala version (2.10) which was not matching the version required by Spark (2.12) but it seems to work well so far.